# email automation and open tracking with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation, gmail, tracking

I wrote a VBA macro that can send email automatically with a Gmail account and it's working perfectly, but I want also to add open tracking, meaning I want to know when the receiver opens the Email, how can I do that? and if it's not possible with VBA what other method can I use?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Outlook, it would be done like this.

```
With OutMail
.ReadReceiptRequested = True
End With
```

With Gmail, all I can think of is that you need to check 'Request return receipt'.  I don't think you can do that with VBA...that seems to be waayyyy outside the realm of what VBA is capable of.  I think Google will handle this for you though.  See the link below for more info.

https://www.everettcc.edu/files/administration/college-services/information-technology/google/gmail-return-receipt.pdf